# Overflow error for Python program to find cube root

Tags: python-3.x, loops, infinite-loop

I wrote the following code on Python 3.6.0 for finding the cube root on *Spyder* editor.

```
   #Finding the cube root
   #import math
   y=input("Enter a number whose cube root you want to find: ")
   root=float(y)
   #x1=math.pow(root,1/3)
   n=input("Enter the degree of accuracy: ")
   epsilon=float(n)
   x1=root/3.0
   while True:
     if x1>root and abs(root-x1)<=epsilon:
        break
     else:
         x1=1/3*(2*x1+root/(x1**2))
    print("The cube root is", x1)
```

However, the output shows "**Overflow error**" and that the "**result is large**". Then I introduced the following *print* statement:

```
else:
    print(x1)
    x1=1/3*(2*x1+root/(x1**2))
```

And now I discovered that the loop was running infinitely. The *print* statement showed that the correct answer had been reached but the loop never terminated.

Can any body tell me what error have I made and how I can get rid of it without changing the formula to find cube root?

Comment: Part of your if-statement to break the loop is `x1>root`.  If `root` was greater than 1 then `x1` will never be larger than that.  Consider if `root` is `8.0` your algorithm should converge on an `x1` of `2.0`, but `2.0>8.0` will never be true so your if-statement will never let you get to `break`.

Answer (score 0):

How can x1 become greater than root in your code?

secondly you may want to test abs(x1**3 -root)<=epsilon
so try:

```
while True:

   if abs(x1**3 - root) <= epsilon:
       print("The cube root is", x1)
       break

   else:
       x1=1/3*(2*x1+root/(x1**2))
```